# pytest-django: Mock settings.DEBUG

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

To make manual testing easy, I want to create users when the login page gets shown.

```
class LalaLoginView(LoginView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_users()
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def create_users(cls):
        if not settings.DEBUG:
            return
        admin = User.objects.update_or_create(username='admin', defaults=dict(
            is_superuser=True, is_staff=True))[0]
        admin.set_password('admin')
        admin.save()
```

My Test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_users_prod(settings):
    settings.DEBUG=False
    LalaLoginView.create_users()
    assert not User.objects.all().exists()
```

But the mocking of `settings.DEBUG` does not work. In `create_users()` DEBUG is "True".

How to mock `settings.DEBUG` with pytest-django?

Answer (score 2):

You need to uses `override_settings` decorator:

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=False)
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_users_prod(settings):
    LalaLoginView.create_users()
    assert not User.objects.all().exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was between keyboard and chair :-)

This code does work:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_create_users_prod(settings):
    settings.DEBUG=False
    LalaLoginView.create_users()
    assert not User.objects.all().exists()
```

But in my production code I imported `settings` from `mysite`.

After changing this to `from django.conf import settings` the pytest fixture "settings" worked.